# a couple of Bootstrap layout issues

Tags: grid, bootstrap-4

I am having a problem with bootstrap grid. I have 6 items to display with 3 across on each line when screen is MD and then 2 across when SM and then down to 1 when XS. I need a space on the left and right too. I have this and its working apart from the going down to 2 across and it has a space in the middle? Any help appreciated.

The code is :

```
<div class="container-fluid col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
<div id="services" class="container-fluid text-center">
  <h2>Middle text here</h2>
  <br>
  <div class="row slideanim">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img alt="" height="42" src="images/earth.png" width="42" />
      <h4>1</h4>
      <h2>description<</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img alt="" height="42" src="images/plane.png" width="42" />
      <h4>2</h4>
      <h2>description<</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img alt="" height="42" src="images/headset.png" width="42" />
      <h4>3</h4>
      <h2>description<</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row slideanim">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img alt="" height="42" src="images/bus.png" width="42" />
      <h4>4</h4>
      <h2>description<</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img alt="" height="42" src="images/24phone.png" width="42" />
      <h4>5</h4>
      <h2>description<</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img alt="" height="42" src="images/clock.png" width="42" />
      <h4>">5</h4>
      <h2>description</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't need to nest multiple containers.
2. Remember bootstrap uses 12 columns layout. So if you want 2 items in a row, use class `.col-{}-6`. If you want 3 items in a row, use class `.col-{}-4` to make up total 12 columns.
3. The offset class has been changed. Please refer to the documentation.

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/91245/